# Scalar multiplication not working with image vector

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've imported an image and converted it to a vector, now I want to multiply it by a scalar. I'm getting very odd behavior.

```
import numpy
import Image

image = Image.open("./yalefaces/subject01.gif").convert("L")
vector = numpy.asarray(image).flatten()
print vector
print vector * 2
```

The response I get:

```
[130 130 130 ...,  68  68  68]
[  4   4   4 ..., 136 136 136]
```

Why do I not get the expected result, `[260 260 260 ..., 136 136 136]`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when I call `numpy.asarray` on the image, I get a vector of `uint8`-s. The reason I get 4 where I expect 2*130 = 260 is because 4 is 260 modulo 256. The solution is to cast to, say, floats:

```
 vector = vector.astype(numpy.float32)
 vector = vector * 2
```

If I want to save the resulting image, I need to convert the vector back to uint8:

```
 vector = vector.astype(numpy.uint8)
 i = Image.fromarray(vector, "L")
 i.save("out.gif")
```

Answer (score -1):

This should give you what you need:

```
numpy.multiply(vector,2)
```

Comment: No, I still get the wrong result. Could it be relevant that `vector` is an `ndarray`?